# Kotlin date picker library for multiplatfor

Tags: kotlin, datepicker, kotlin-multiplatform

I am looking for library for kotlin multiplatform (kmm, kmp) for working with calendar (date picker, like MaterialDatePicker). Does anyone know if this exists?

Comment: DatePickers are platform-dependent, you've to use platform-specific date pickers for each platform.

Comment: The idea behind KMM/KMP is to share business logic. UI should be platform specific unless a compose-driven multiplatform UI comes in the picture.

Comment: @Jigar, why we can not use compose-driven screen to implement date picker?

Comment: @1Avalanche As I said in my comment, you can certainly use compo-driven multiplatform UI toolkit to create a date picker. That's just not Kotlin multiplatform (kmm/kmp) related question, and I was clarifying that.